# Problem understanding proof involving determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, linear-programming

I have problems understanding Theorem 3.2, page 29 from [Theory of Linear and Integer Programming](http://books.google.de/books/about/Theory_of_Linear_and_Integer_Programming.html?id=zEzW5mhppB8C). I don't understand (3): Let $M$ be a matrix in $\mathbb{Q}^{n\times n}$, and let $M_{ij} = a_{ij}/b_{ij}$ for $i$ and $j$ in $[1 \dots n]$,  where $a_{ij}$ and $b_{ij}$  in $\mathbb{Z}$ are coprime and $b_{ij}>0$. Morever, let $\det (M) = a/b$, where $a$ and $b$ are coprime and $b >0$. Then

$$|\det(M)| \leq \prod_{i,j = 1}^{n} (|a_{ij}| +1)\,.$$

Any ideas? Does this follow from the Laplace expansion?

Comment: Please ask questions that are complete. Giving a reference to a book and a page number is not a proper way to pose questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, notice that $\sum_{i=1}^n|a_{ij}|^2\leq \prod_{i=1}^n (|a_{ij}|+1)^2$(Expand the right side.)

Now, by [Hadamard inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard's_inequality) we have $|\det(M)|\leq\prod_{j=1}^n\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n|m_{ij}|^2}$

Now, by hypothesis $|m_{ij}|\leq|a_{ij}|$. Thus, $|\det(M)|\leq\prod_{j=1}^n\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n|a_{ij}|^2}$.

Finally, by our first inequality we obtain $|\det(M)|\leq\prod_{j=1}^n\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n|a_{ij}|^2}\leq \prod_{j=1}^n\prod_{i=1}^n (|a_{ij}|+1)$.